# Элемент теряет ширину при hover

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Здравствуйте! Есть некий список, каждый пункт которого имеет соответствующую иконку. При наведении на пункт списка иконка должна поворачиваться. Проблема в том, что при `hover` псевдоэлемент с иконкой принимает нулевую ширину. Вопроса два: почему и как это исправить?

```css
.some-list {
  list-style: none;
}
.some-list > li {
  position: relative;
}
.some-list > li:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  content: '\f105';
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: all .25s;
}
.some-list > li:hover:before {
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
}
```

```html
<ul class="some-list">
  <li>Some text for first item</li>
  <li>Some text for second item</li>
  <li>Some text for third item</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ea0959dcb8.js"></script>
```

Comment: А я всегда думал, что при трансформации объект сохраняет свой физбокс, судя по всему - нет. Попробуй иконки во враппер запихнуть с фиксированной шириной, либо с минимальной например. И да, там ось не та указана, нужно по Z вертеть.

Comment: Функция `rotateY` является 3D трансформацией. Физ. бокс сохраняется и здесь, просто он вращается в глубь экрана, а т.к. он абсолютно плоский то при повороте на 90 градусов становится невидимым. Для 2D нужно заменить `rotateY` на `rotate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как поворачиваться?

```css
.some-list {
  list-style: none;
}
.some-list > li {
  position: relative;
}
.some-list > li:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  content: '\f105';
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: all .25s;
}
.some-list > li:hover:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<ul class="some-list">
  <li>Some text for first item</li>
  <li>Some text for second item</li>
  <li>Some text for third item</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ea0959dcb8.js"></script>
```

```css
.some-list {
  list-style: none;
}
.some-list > li {
  position: relative;
}
.some-list > li:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  content: '\f105';
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: all .25s;
}
.some-list > li:hover:before {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<ul class="some-list">
  <li>Some text for first item</li>
  <li>Some text for second item</li>
  <li>Some text for third item</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ea0959dcb8.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
.some-list > li:hover:before {
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
}
```

Есть предположение... Попробуйте мысленно повернуть элемент с условно нулевой "глубиной". Возьмите лист бумаги и поверните его вокруг оси Y на 90 градусов. Вы получите сторону с "толщиной" листа. А у символа толщины нет. Мб поэтому

Answer (score 2):

```css
.some-list {
  list-style: none;
}
.some-list > li {
  position: relative;
}
a{
    width: 20px;
    display: inline;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
.some-list >li>a:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  content: '\f105';
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: all .25s;
}
.some-list li>  a:hover:before  {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<ul class="some-list">
  <li><a></a>Some text for first item</li>
  <li><a></a>Some text for second item</li>
  <li><a></a>Some text for third item</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ea0959dcb8.js"></script>
```

Обернув поворачиваемый элемент, мы всегда имеем фиксированный блок, мимо которого мышка не пройдет =) Т.е. анимация применяется на :before блок, а вот сам блок a существует неизменно

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `transform: rotateY(180deg);`. Поворот на 180 градусов.

Comment: Зачем это пробовать?

Comment: при 90 нулевая ширина